# Javascript Library for Mobile Touch Drawing of Closed Poly Shapes

Tags: javascript, charts, draw

I want to draw shapes on mobile screens via touch that define a closed area polygon. I would also like to interact with those polygons by say subtracting or adding area to a polygon based on the area of another polygon.

I have javascript experience with several HTML5 frameworks and would be looking to integrate this with a sencha + phonegap app but would be open to any other option that cater better to this.

Any obvious answers? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like paperjs.org has pretty much all I need. I'm still researching so if anyone else has an idea i'm all ears. Thanks!

some references:
closed shape polygons using paths:
http://scriptographer.org/tutorials/paths/working-with-path-items/

using two shapes to create one via addition subtraction:
http://scriptographer.org/tutorials/paths/geometric-operations/